# How can I recover a dropped table?

Tags: oracle-12c

I am using Oracle 12c Standard Edition.

I accidentally drop the table and try to recover it, but the table does not appear in Recyclebin.

I think the tablespace is due to **SYSTEM**.

```
Create table test(
 aaa varchar2(20)
 ....
)
 TABLESPACE SYSTEM
 STORAGE (
  NEXT 1024K
 )
/
```

thank!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to recover the table from your database backup. You do have a backup right? - [hot2use](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/15356/hot2use)

The real question is: why are you creating tables in the `SYSTEM` tablespace? Don't do that. - [a-horse-with-no-name](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1822/a-horse-with-no-name)

Comment: I did not and I can not understand why I did this..  Fortunately, it has the 'sys' privilege. Is there no way?